# SQL Merge with Partial Matching tables

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have investigated lots of posts relating to SQL merging of two tables, and am very familiar with merging in SQL, but this one has me stumped. Here is the scenario: I have a table of values which are stored by Grade and Currency, i.e.
GradeID = 3, Rate = 175, CurrencyID = 5.
There are five grades, a different value for each and these are the default values for each grade in GBP (CurrencyID = 5).
I have another table with an extra column of Fiscal Period, which is a 1st of the month date to which the rate applies, i.e.
GradeID = 3, Rate = 150, FiscalPeriodID = 95, CurrencyID = 5.
Not all values for each grade, fiscal period and currency will be different from the default, so users will only enter differences where necessary. I have a Windows form for the user to view and update these values, but am struggling to show the results of both tables together.
The ideal solution for a case where there is no stored data, i.e. only the default values apply, is that the screen will show the default values at the current fiscal period i.e. 95 = 01/11/2017, but where there are values which have been entered, the table will show the changed rows by grade but grouped by each fiscal period which has a non-default value.
The first part of setting the current fiscal period for the default values is relatively easy:

```
SELECT [RateID], [GradeID], [ChargeRate],   
(SELECT [FiscalPeriodID] FROM [dbo].[FiscalPeriod] WHERE MONTH([FiscalPeriod]) = 
MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR([FiscalPeriod]) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AS [FiscalPeriodID]   
,[CurrencyID]   
FROM [dbo].[DefaultChargeRateByLevel]
```

But what I'd like to do is perform one query that does either this simple selection (when no results returned for any fiscal period) or a merge of the default and updated values to show groups of 5 values per fiscal period.
My initial thought was to populate two temporary tables with the results from each query then perform a merge, but I can't figure out how to populate the fiscal period for each 'group of values. This is what i have so far, but it fails with the following error: ***Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FiscalPeriodID', table 'tempdb.dbo.#TempTarget***

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTarget') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempTarget
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempSource') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempSource

SELECT  
    [GradeID]
    ,[ChargeRate]
    ,[FiscalPeriodID]
    ,[CurrencyID]       
INTO #TempTarget 
FROM (SELECT 
    [GradeID]
    ,[ChargeRate]
    ,[FiscalPeriodID]
    ,[CurrencyID]
FROM 
    [dbo].[ChargeRateByProjectAndLevel]) AS A

SELECT * FROM #TempTarget

SELECT  
    [GradeID]
    ,[ChargeRate]
    ,[FiscalPeriodID]
    ,[CurrencyID]       
INTO #TempSource
FROM (SELECT 
    D.[GradeID]
    ,D.[ChargeRate]
    ,M.[FiscalPeriodID]
    ,D.[CurrencyID]
FROM 
    [dbo].[DefaultChargeRateByLevel] AS D
LEFT JOIN #TempTarget AS M ON M.[GradeID] = D.[GradeID]
                    AND M.[CurrencyID] = D.[CurrencyID]
) AS B

SELECT * FROM #TempSource

/* Now merge rates data from temp table to FxRates table */
    MERGE #TempTarget AS [Target]
    USING  #TempSource AS [Source]
    ON [Source].[GradeID]           = [Target].[GradeID]        
    AND [Source].[CurrencyID]       = [Target].[CurrencyID]     

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (
        [GradeID]
        ,[ChargeRate]
        ,[FiscalPeriodID]
        ,[CurrencyID]
    )
    VALUES  (
       [Source].[GradeID]
        ,[Source].[ChargeRate]
        ,[Source].[FiscalPeriodID]
        ,[Source].[CurrencyID]
    );

SELECT * FROM #TempTarget
```

Comment: Sample data will help. Will the final output be for one fiscal period only or many? One way is to define your base dataset and outer join to the default dataset. Another way is to write a query which contains, as a column, another query that picks out the correct rate (a correlated select)

Comment: Yes @Nick.McDermaid, many fiscal periods. So ultimately there will n groups of 5 rows, each group containing a mix of default and non-default values. It will only show fiscal periods that have been updated. The default values can be seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/72t3ul6h21ovdgx/Default.JPG?dl=0) and sample updated values [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jtmx1nc30u8e3x2/Entered.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: So basically you need every combination of fiscal period, currency, grade for a given period range. Next to these you need to show any defined value. If there is no defined value you show the default. If that's correct you need to first generate your base dataset (every combination of fiscal period, currency, grade), then you outer join to the defined value. Then you join (maybe outer join) to the default value. Then your rate column has an expression that decides which rate to pick (probably using `COALESCE`

Comment: Yes, that pretty much sums it up. Thanks, i'll work through and see how I get on.